# set Country code and mobile number from contact odoo website

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-15

ODOO 15 In `contact` backend form view we have `phone` and in contact configuration we have  `country code` as well but in `XML` I have 2 input tag, I want to save country code and phone number, I had successful done that and is passed to backend as well but now I want is

in my 1st input tag there should be default value which will `+91` and in second there should be 10 digit number and when I input value the value should start from `9` not from `0` start value for a number cannot be `0`.
below is my code:

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="mobile" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Mobile Number
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 mobile">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm custom_class"
        name="country_code" id="country_code" maxlength="4" size="4" t-att-value="country_code or +91" autocomplete="off"/>
        <input type="tel" minlength="10" maxlength="10" class="form-control form-control-sm custom_class" id="mobile_number" autocomplete="off"
        name="mobile_number" t-att-value="mobile_numer" pattern="^[0-9]{10}$"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

my code is accepting 10 digit but i can start from 0 also i cannot set +91 in the code please let me know where i am doing it wrong
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you want to save the whole phone number as a single field, you need to write the JS and implement its return as a single field, or do that in Python part. If you just want not to have 0 at the beginning of a second field, change your pattern to this `pattern="^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$"`.

Comment: I have already completed it thanks....